# CKEditor: Escape editor focus from inline editor via JS (without requiring mouse click)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm working on a note-taking app that uses [CKEditor's inline mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html) to expose dynamically created editable divs. (I'm using CKEditor version 4.5.8.)

When using the inline editor, you can click your mouse away from the div to leave editing mode, which results in the following behavior changes:

- The blue highlight around the div disappears
- The blinking cursor disappears
- Keypresses are no longer "typed" into the div (ie. the editor is now inactive).

But I can't figure out how to **escape editor focus** (ie. reproduce the above changes) without requiring the user to physically click the mouse. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Called Jquery `.blur()` on the inline-editable element: This visually removes focus and `CKEDITOR.currentInstance` becomes `null`; but keypresses still cause characters to be added to the div, which re-activates focus.
- Called Jquery `.removeClass('cke_focus')` on the inline-editable element - no visible effect.
- Called Jquery `.click()` or `.focus()` on other elements on the page - no visible effect.
- Called `CKEDITOR.currentInstance.focusManager.blur()` - no visible effect.
- Called `CKEDITOR.currentInstance.container.fire('blur')` - no visible effect.
- Called `CKEDITOR.currentInstance.element.fire('blur')` - no visible effect.
- Called `CKEDITOR.currentInstance.destroy()` - it looks like the editor automatically re-initializes after destruction due to the `contenteditable="true"` attribute, or something like that. At any rate the div retains focus and continues to trap keypresses.

All I want is to recreate what happens when you *click away from an inline editing div*: the focus indicators disappear, and keypresses no longer add text to the div. Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: Thanks @Dekel, no I didn't check your answer yet because you posted at the middle of the night my time. But I do vote and accept answers if they work for me, so no need to worry that I've forgotten about yours.

Comment: sure :) no problem, just wanted to make sure you got a notification about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to combine the `blur` with removing all selection ranges that you currently have:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.on('keydown', function(event) {  
        if (event.data.getKey() == 27) {
            $(CKEDITOR.currentInstance.element.$).blur();
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
    });
});
```

And a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/bwuhp14s/